# Oracle Trigger creation with compilation errors and PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Tags: oracle, sequence

I met this problem several days, i generate the following sql from power designer, and run it at oracle, but it throws the error "Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.".

```
drop trigger "tib_material_classify"
/

create trigger "tib_material_classify" before insert
on "material_classify" for each row
declare
    integrity_error  exception;
    errno            integer;
    errmsg           char(200);
    dummy            integer;
    found            boolean;

begin
    --  column ""id"" uses sequence "seq_material_classify"
    select "seq_material_classify".Nextval into :new."id" from dual;

--  errors handling
exception
    when integrity_error then
       raise_application_error(errno, errmsg);
end;
/
```

and i Show errors, it throws the following, i don't known where i did wrong, i need your help. thanks very much!

```
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
10/12    PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

Comment: Does this sequence really exist? Try to fetch the currval using this seq only.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times. We are all volunteers here and you are not entitled to an instant response to your question. Duplicate questions waste everybody's time and pollute the site, making it less useful as a resource for other people.